# Need a hand altering a theme

Tags: blocks

I'm using a theme called Danland, and I want to change the Recent Posts block to show only post title and publication date. As it stands it shows 3 columns, one of which is post title, and the last two of which are blank when you are not logged in and say "edit" and "delete" when you are logged in. I also want to kill the table border.

I can't find the right css file to edit. Using firebug to ID the td and other tags to kill to get rid of the extra columns, but I can't find them in the theme files. Firebug IDs them as being in style.css, but there's nothing there. Where does this code live?

Comment: Link to site: www.naphikes.com

Comment: Hello. Could you please edit your question's title? I was tempted to vote to close as too broad, but it seems you have a legitimate question, just formatted it unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to views admin interface and check the views name as Recent post(display type block), views gives  you flexibility for adding any number of fields your content type has, also it will allow you to have custom classes to fields that you will be needing to theme.About classes and ids already there, they are coming from views theming you do not have to touch there all you have to do is add fields you want, while adding it will allow you to style it by adding wrapper divs or other html element.Once you finish with editing the view,check the block in firebug you will see your calsses and ids working there, then add css for it in your Danland theme .css file.

Key Points which may help you:

- how to add/remove fields from view
- how to add custom classes to the fields in views
- Once done style it using your theme css file.